# Oozie service not starting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, oozie

i have a CDH4 cluster running Map-Reduce V1. when I tried to install oozie CDh4 from tarball and configured it as per the instructions given at 
https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Oozie+Installation#OozieInstallation-Configuringthehadoopversion

On starting the service i get the following error in logs

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
    11 Oct, 2012 11:51:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor oozie.xml

    ERROR: Oozie could not be started

    REASON: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils

    Stacktrace:
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils
        at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:349)
        at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.<init>(Services.java:107)
        at org.apache.oozie.servlet.ServicesLoader.contextInitialized(ServicesLoader.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see this in the CDH4 docs, but under CDH3u3 you had to copy the hadoop-core libray into `<oozie-home>/lib`.  That jar contains the missing class from your stack trace.

Edit:

For the life of me, I can't find this in the docs anywhere for cdh3u3, either.  So, I copied it and other jars I needed, but I don't remember where I read this.

Comment: actually thers some problem with the CDH4 tarball, in the installation guide it is clearly mentioned that the directory oozie-server-0.20 should be used for MR1 while the directory oozie-server is used for YARN.
all this path had to be edited in CATALINA_BASE environment variable in the file oozie-env.sh. But the tarball does not contain any directory named oozie-server-0.20 for MR1.

Comment: so i added all the hadoop-MR1 libraries to the `/oozie-3.1.3-cdh4.0.1/oozie-server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib` , and the service is now running. but i havent checked any working examples over it.

Comment: Cool.  Glad you got it running. :)